# Enterprise library 5.0 in a c# class library project

Tags: .net, project, enterprise-library, class-library

I have a c# class library project in VS 2010 which outputs a dll. I added a executable project in my solution that I need to start with so I can debug my dll. I don't have a host application which has the app.config. Can I use Enterprise Libray (especially exception handling) in my class library project? If yes, how can I define the Exception Handling Policies since there is no app.config?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Fluent Configuration API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx) with enterprise library 5

With respects to [Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx#fluent_api_exceptionhandling). (from msdn)

```
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();

builder.ConfigureExceptionHandling()
       .GivenPolicyWithName("MyPolicy")
       .ForExceptionType<NullReferenceException>()
         .LogToCategory("General")
           .WithSeverity(System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Warning)
           .UsingEventId(9000)
         .WrapWith<InvalidOperationException>()
           .UsingMessage("MyMessage")
         .ThenNotifyRethrow();

var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace(configSource);
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current 
  = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer(configSource);
```